# Move 'ul' element into the previous adjacent 'li'` element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a poorly formatted sidebar `aside` which I have no control over the structure. It automatically generates a `ul` from the body of the document, but incorrectly is placing the sub-lists outside of the respective parent element.

Valid html code should be along the lines of:

```html
<ul>
 <li>
  <a>Text</a>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a>Text</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Where the child `ul` elements are nested inside the previous `li` element.

In the system I am using there is also the ability to have chapter headings, which should be the top level `li` elements in the main list

```html
<ul>
 <li><a>Text</a></li>  <-- chapter title
 <li><a>Text</a></li>  <-- chapter title
 <li><a>Text</a>       <-- chapter title
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a>Text</a>        <-- sub-chapter title
   </li>
  </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Below is a test html structure and some of the javascript I've been trying to get to work.

At the moment it is currently iterating through the loop of all the found `li` elements and adding the next `ul` element into it. However, because it is doing it top down its running into a continual loop of adding in the element.

I tried using the `.previousElementSibling` but that was returning `null` for a lot of the elements in the list when trying to insert it to the element above.

This is where I'm up to, and hopefully someone can guide me to the correct way of working this data.

```js
// -- get the sidebar list
const sidebarList = document.querySelector('div.sidebar-nav > ul');

const reorder = ((list) => {
    const listItems = list.querySelectorAll(':scope li');
    listItems.forEach((element) => {

    // -- last h6 wont have a next sibling
    if (element.nextElementSibling === null) return;

    // -- if it is a second sub heading skip
    if (element.nextElementSibling.tagName !== 'UL') return;

    // -- add into the next element
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + element.nextElementSibling.innerHTML
    });
})(sidebarList);
```

```css
/*
------
HOW IT SHOULD RENDER
------
<aside class="sidebar">
 <div class="sidebar-nav">
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a>Heading level 1</a>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a>Heading level 2</a>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a>Heading level 3</a>
        <ul>
         <li>
          <a>Heading Level 4 - 1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a>Heading Level 4 - 2</a>
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a>Heading Level 5</a>
            <ul>
             <li>
              <a>Heading level 6</a>
             </li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a>Heading level 1</a>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a>Heading level 2</a>
      <ul>
       <li>
        <a>Heading level 3</a>
        <ul>
         <li>
          <a>Heading Level 4 - 1</a>
         </li>
         <li>
          <a>Heading Level 4 - 2</a>
          <ul>
           <li>
            <a>Heading Level 5</a>
            <ul>
             <li>
              <a>Heading level 6</a>
             </li>
            </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</aside>
*/
```

```html
<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a>Heading level 1</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Heading level 2</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Heading level 3</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Heading Level 4 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Heading Level 4 - 2</a></li>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Heading Level 5</a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a>Heading level 6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
      <li><a>Heading level 1</a></li>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Heading level 2</a></li>
        <ul>
          <li><a>Heading level 3</a></li>
          <ul>
            <li><a>Heading Level 4 - 1</a></li>
            <li><a>Heading Level 4 - 2</a></li>
            <ul>
              <li><a>Heading Level 5</a></li>
              <ul>
                <li><a>Heading level 6</a></li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </ul>
        </ul>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: That's an ugly mess of improperly placed `<ul>` but the browser won't accept ul as child of ul and rejects some of them. The problem could be do all browsers reject the same? I'm not really clear what final result should look like

Comment: @charlietfl yeah sorry, its so minor or a change. what I'm trying to achieve it to insert the child `ul` into the parent `li` elements. that's compliant, whereas the `ul` next to the `li` is not

Comment: My bad. Seems browser is accepting the nested UL . In FF anyway.  I get leary of these sorts of issues as I remember older days when IE would do something completely different than FF when rendering invalid markup. So what works doing this mod in FF may not work in Safari or Opera for example

Comment: Yeah i agree! as far as my tests the major browsers seem to render it correctly regardless of the nested nature. its more coming down to being able to manipulate the data when an `ul` is next to a `li` and saying this *is* your parent but its outside of you

Comment: I’m confused about what structure you want to end up with. Is it just one list?

Comment: @AHaworth essentially. in the example, Heading 6 should be inside Heading 5, and Heading 5 should be inside Heading 4.. all the way to the top level Heading 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
document.querySelectorAll('ul').forEach(function(list) {
  let prev = list.previousElementSibling;

  if (!prev) return;

  if (list.parentNode.nodeName == "UL" && prev.nodeName == "LI") {
    prev.appendChild(list);
  }
});
```

It goes through every `ul`, checking whether the `ul` has a direct `ul` parent and preceding `li`. If it does, it appends the `ul` to the preceding `li`.

https://jsfiddle.net/ago8by90/